# Prove logical equivalence of formulas with following properties

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Let $P$ be the set of all propositional variables and  $v : P \rightarrow \{ \top, \bot \}$ be a valuation such that $v(p) = \top$, for every $p \in P$. Prove that if $A \in \mathcal{Form}$ and $B \in \mathcal{Form(\{ \wedge, \Rightarrow\})}$ then $A$ is logically equivalent to $B$ if and only if $\tilde{v}(A) = \top$.

So, what I could prove is that if $A$ and $B$ are logically equivalent, then $B \vDash A$. It is not hard to prove that $\tilde{v}(B) = \top$ (using induction by complexity of formula $B$), so $\tilde{v}(A) = \top$, also.

However, I could not find a connection between the given hypotheses for the other direction. Every help is appreciated.

Comment: You already showed that $\tilde{v}(B) = \top$, right? The only thing logically equivalent to a true thing is a true thing. So aren't you already done?

Comment: Shouldn't I now prove that for every valuation that $B$ is true, $A$ is also true and vice versa? We only know that $\tilde{v}(B) = \top$, not that for all valuations that $B$ is true, $A$ is also.

Comment: @James Far from being trivial, it is false. $\tilde v$ is only one valuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converse is false. Let $B$ be $x_1\to x_2$ and $A$ be $x_1\lor x_2.$ Then $\tilde v(A) = \top,$ but $A$ is not logically equivalent to $B.$ What is probably intended is to show that a formula $A$ is equivalent to *some* $B$ that only involves the connectives $\to $ and $\land$ if and only if $\tilde v(A) = \top.$

Your proof still goes through for the one direction. For the converse, we can use the easy-to-see fact that if $\tilde v(A) = \top,$ then the conjunctive normal form of $A$ must have at least one un-negated disjunct in each clause. Then, consider a generic clause satisfying this requirement, $$ x\lor x_1\lor \ldots \lor x_n \lor \lnot y_1\lor \ldots \lor \lnot y_n$$ where the $x$'s and $y$'s are propositional variables.

Using Boolean algebra, we can find the equivalence $x\lor  x_1 = (x\to x_1)\to x_1$ and if we iterate this for all the $x_i$ we can express the clause as $$ \phi\lor \lnot y_1\lor \ldots \lor \lnot y_n$$ where $\phi$ only uses $\to.$ Again using Boolean algebra $\phi\lor \lnot y_1 = y_1\to\phi,$ so repeating this, we express the entire clause only using the $\to$ connective. So our CNF is equivalent to a conjunction of clauses only using $\to,$ so only uses $\land$ and $\to.$

Comment: Is there a way to solve this problem without using Boolean algebra. Where are supposed to learn about it in several weeks.

Comment: @Nemanja I’m not sure why I called it “Boolean algebra” I guess I thought the easiest way to see it was through the algebraic manipulation of the connectives. But the key here is that these manipulations take statements to logically equivalent statements. For your purposes you could just verify by truth table reasoning that the equivalences hold.